# match multiple parts of an id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option and the id is random but has two static parts. And i try to catch the value. For a single match like below it's working.

```
var beginhour = ($('select[id^="iZondagbegin_"]').val());
```

But for an ID like this => "iZondagbegin_f9121cfb-8e8d-4b07-80f4-05b7aac8c406_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes" how can i do this?

Comment: You are using Attribute Starts With Selector, so what is the problem?

Comment: not able to understand qus???

Comment: You can use name attribute of element

Comment: Is your select is asp control?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but I guess what you are looking for is:

```
var beginhour = ($('select[id^="iZondagbegin_"][id$="_$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]').val());
var beginminutes = ($('select[id^="iZondagbegin_"][id$="_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes"]').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use 2 selector condition?

If yes, these 2 should work:

`$("select[id^='iZondagbegin_'][id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']")`

or

`$("select[id^='iZondagbegin_']").filter("[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']")`

Comment: @user3764970, consider accepting the answer which helped you the most (its a way of saying thanks). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work